# No me encuentra el ejecutable de python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Mi duda es que pongo en la consola cmd

```
C:\Users\Jorge>python --version
```

y no me sale la version como dice el tuto sino que me sale

> "python" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,

programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Alguien me puede iluminar que parece que estoy haciendo algo mal

Comment: Necesitas colocar la ruta del binario de python en las variables de sistema de tu sistema operativo,ç

Comment: escribes `where python` te aparecera la ruta, esa ruta agregala a tu path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soluciona todos los conflictos instalando Anaconda. Inclusive viene con Spyder, un gran IDE para Python.

Descargá la versión según tu equipo y sistema operativo aquí >

[ANACONDA](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo, pero responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, por favor lee [answer], edita y explica como esto soluciona el problema del OP.

Answer (score 11):

de seguro no habilitaste incluiste el path en el momento de la instalación de python.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de no querer reinstalar el programa haremos lo siguiente

lo agregamos de forma manual:

- con windows+R  con el comando `sysdm.cpl` abrimos la ventana de propiedades del sistema
- en opciones avanzadas , click en variable de entorno
- en variable de entorno de sistema y buscamos `path` y click editar y al final con `;` agregas

---

```
; C:\Python34
```

> en lo que es mi versión de python 3.4 tu tendrás que adaptarla conforme a tu versión

**Que es PATH?**

Es una variable del Sistema Operativo donde se especifican las rutas en las cuales el intérprete de comandos (CMD) debe buscar los programas a ejecutar cuando colocamos un nombre/comando en consola.

Comment: lo agregamos de forma manual:

Comment: Gracias era eso mismo me dormi jajaj gracias

Comment: @JorgeQuintana recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada...